# how to handle errors in Fetch javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch

I have an error handling code that works perfectly fine but shows those red errors in the console.
I tried the .catch() functions but it did not work, the error still shows and the code inside the .catch() also doesn't run

Here's the working code:

```
function getData(key) {
fetch(key)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.ok === false) {
            res.json()
                .then(e => {
                    alert(e.message)
                })
        }
        else {
            res.json()
        }
    })
    .then(json => {
        data = json;
    })
```

}

I'm just trying to display the error message to the user without those console errors.

Comment: `those red errors` - more specific?

Comment: I mean the errors returned from the server

Comment: I know you do.  What are they.

Comment: I'm just trying to show an alert when an error appears like a 404-Not Found or 400- Bad Request, like that

Comment: Can you show the error?